# Liking a friend's Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

How can I get my friends to like someone else's Facebook page? I have a friend who has a page for a film he is making, and I would like to ask my friends to like it, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I [edited](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59865) this question in same way but it got rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Login to your Facebook account and open your friend's Facebook page (if you have already liked that page it will appear in your profile at right hand side in page column or you can search that page by typing page name in search bar). Once you open the page you will see "invite friends to like this page" in right hand side. Just click on that and select each and every friends or whom you want to invite and send the invitation.